# How to use Hadoop for reading 10 million records from csv file and create pdf for each record

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Below question is more aligned to MapReduce than Hadoop.
I need to know how to use hadoop for the below use case.

**Usecase : Read 10 million records(Each record having 20 column) from a tsv 
file and generate a pdf for each record.**

I have below unit programs available with me.

- Program Description: A static method which accepts a java object(represents a 
              single record), and returns a FilePath String(created pdf).
- Program Name : PdfUtil.createPdf(Record record) - returns FilePath String.

What I should do in map method and what I should do in the reduce method.
If I call PdfUtil.createPdf method inside map method of Mapper, what I should do in Reduce methos of Reducer.?

Comment: why would you want to Reduce something?

Comment: Also why Hadoop for that? You'll end up with 10 mio. of PDFs in HDFS which isn't really that great.

Comment: @Axarydax : Can I code it in hadoop without Reducing..?
I am new to hadoop. Can we have empty reduce() method and having everyuthing in map() method..?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, This is for learning purpose. I want to showcase that hadoop can solve this problem faster. Thats why I want to use hadoop.

Comment: @user2179012 I very much doubt that this is fast at all, but have fun trying it ;)

Comment: hadoop can solve the problem faster than *what?* You *still* have to generate 10 million pdfs, and this isn't the right tool for the job

Comment: @Axarydax 

Below is my idea. Using hadoop I distribute the data into 10 machines(10 data nodes) and all machines will run in parallel. Instead of letting one single machine generate all the 10 million pdf,  10 machines will generate these pdfs.

Comment: @Axarydax 
So I believe it can complete the entire work in short time(using hadoop) than having a java program which runs in single machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Suresh:Yes you can code in Map Reduce without using Reduce Method.

Just Write the Map Method, call PdfUtil.createPdf using it.

One thing I am confused of, do you need a PDF file per record ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Yes, I need to create one pdf for each Record in the input file.

Comment: u can do that in mappers. its very easy because file will be processed in  mappers record by record